# Elasticsearch node.js geo_distance filter

Tags: node.js, filter, elasticsearch, geolocation

I'm using the elasticsearch module in a nodejs app in order to find document by geo_points.

according to http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search, i'm trying to do this :

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  type: 'mytype',
  body: {
    filtered : {
        query : {
            match_all : {}
        },
        filter : {
            geo_distance : {
                distance : "200km",
                coordiates : {
                    lat : 40,
                    lon : -70
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.hits;
    console.log(hits, "items");
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error on geo_distance");
});
```

But I always got a search parsing error.

Does someone got an idea?

Thx

Comment: make sure that you have the lat/long mapped to the data type geo_point in your ES mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The mapping is good and I can access the results with a regular http request. I tried both with a geo_point [XX, YY] and a geopoint {lat : xx, lon: xx}. Both works in http but not in the API

Comment: Does someone has an idea? Sounds obvious but this makes me crazy ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly, I found the correct syntax / parameters :

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  type: 'mytype',
  body: {
      from: from,
      size: size,
      query: {
        filtered: {
                filter: {
                    geo_distance: {
                        distance: '100000km',
                        coordiates: {
                            lat: 0.0,
                            lon: 0.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.hits;
    console.log(hits.length, "items around");
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error on geo_distance (coordiates)");
});
```

Thx Jhilden for your help.